# After page refresh ModalPopUpExxtender Appears again?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `UpdatePanel` inside update panel I am using `ModalPopUpExtender`. I have one `userControl` inside this I am using `ModalPopUpExtender`. I have a `LinkButton`. At `Onclick` event of `LinkButton` I am showing `ModalPopUpExtender`. It works fine But once I refresh the page after clicking on `LinkButton` `ModalPopUpExtender` apperas again at every page refresh and it happens only after click on `LinkButton`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
            btnOK.Enabled = false;
            PopUpExtender.Hide();
        }
        PopUpExtender.Hide();
    }

    protected void lbDownloadContacts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopUpExtender.Show();
        Timer1.Enabled = true;
        btnOK.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LinkButton` may be not inside `UpdatePanel`. Make sure that your `LinkButton` is inside `UpdatePanel` .